# Cannot resolve symbol 'R' please help me

Tags: r.java-file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
go
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: main thing is when i am creating new project every time it display unable to run mksdcard sdk tool. and when i want to create AVD i need to create at every time it is not saving my created one and when i run it take very long time to respond in some cases it is moving on but no running app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need have an import for R - but your developer tool must import this dependence automatically. Probably you have an error in other code or some problems with your resources. Watch your error logs.

Comment: Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool ubuntusudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6

Comment: Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool ubuntu  sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6

Comment: Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool ubuntu sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6   tried this also but there is no use